# Reading Html from another website and analyze html tree

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, loops

I hope this is not duplicate.

I read another website via php like this:

```
$homepage = @file_get_contents($url);

if ( $homepage == false ) {
  //...oh dear
}
```

Now I want to get html tag node (jquery anchor) from html say I have this code

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        xxx
      </td>
      <td>
        yyy
      </td>
      <td>
        zzz
      </td>
    <tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I want to get array with "xxx", "yyy", "zzz".

Normaly I would use jquery/js and loop throu `$('div table tr td').Val();` but how can I do it with php?

Comment: You could try -> `https://github.com/punkave/phpQuery`

Comment: Thx. I think this or another github solution will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can use [PHP Html Parser](https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser)

Example code :

```
require "vendor/autoload.php";
use PHPHtmlParser\Dom;

$dom = new Dom;
$dom->load('<div class="all"><p>Hey bro, <a href="google.com">click here</a><br /> :)</p></div>');
$a = $dom->find('a')[0];
echo $a->text; // "click here"
```

Comment: Thx. I think this will be fine solution. Just of curiosity: maybe is there a way to somehow connect jquery with another url?

Comment: best way I found would be https://github.com/punkave/phpQuery but it doesn't like xml parser for some reason, and I need it so I used simplehtmldom and it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with using both phpQuery and PHP html due to my serwer parser so finally I used: https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/

Example code:

```
include('files/libs/simplehtmldom_1_9/simple_html_dom.php');

// get DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://poland_is_great.pl/');


// find all links
foreach($html->find('a') as $e) 
    echo $e->href . '<br>';

//table loop
foreach($html->find('tr') as $tr) 
{
    foreach($tr->find('td') as $td)
    {
        echo $td->innertext . '<br>';
    }
}
```